# Merging cells in google spreadsheet

Tags: java, javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

There is a way for [merging cells](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141104) in Google spreadsheet finally. But I can not find API for doing this. Am I missing something?

Comment: mcfinnigan, because I'm looking for java or javascript API.

Comment: I doubt there is going to be a java api any time soon.Javascript is more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#merge) for doing it using Google Apps Script. But this API is only accessible using Apps Script code, not really a public thing that you can call from java or "regular" javascript.

Well, you could publish the script as service and develop your own protocol to do it, which you could call from "external" programs. But that's kind of cumbersome. Much better if you could just write everything in Apps Script.